KeyCloak - How to configure the Username policy
I am currently required to configure the Username and Password policy from the KeyCloak app.
Surely, I could configure the Password Policy, from the Authenticatio -> Password Policy Screen. However, I could not find the screen to configure the Username Policy.
I found that KeyCloak does not have the configuration to achieve it. this means KeyCloak does not have restrictions on username (as you can see in this link: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/9443), however, this input is older, and honesty I do not know if this feature was included after this question.
My requirement is associated with:

Username Minimum Length.
Requires at least one number in Username.

We are using the KeyCloak version 9.0.2.
Thanks in Advance.

I am using version 24.0.1 and have this feature under Realm Settings -> User Profile -> username. If you don't have it, you probably need to upgrade.
